# How to improve query performace after a EXPLAIN ANALYZE

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I'm trying to understand what actions I could take following this `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`. I have created a lot of indexes but Postgresql does not seem to use theme because I can see only Seq Scan.

```
Hash Left Join  (cost=6351.51..13444.83 rows=109654 width=525) (actual time=85.420..378.647 rows=144352 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: (player."teamId" = team.id)
  ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=5988.22..11573.79 rows=109654 width=204) (actual time=74.252..257.521 rows=144352 loops=1)
        Hash Cond: (goal."playerId" = player.id)
        ->  Seq Scan on goal  (cost=0.00..1695.03 rows=64203 width=102) (actual time=0.012..10.510 rows=64203 loops=1)
        ->  Hash  (cost=2903.54..2903.54 rows=109654 width=102) (actual time=74.050..74.051 rows=109654 loops=1)
              Buckets: 32768  Batches: 4  Memory Usage: 3949kB
              ->  Seq Scan on player  (cost=0.00..2903.54 rows=109654 width=102) (actual time=0.011..18.871 rows=109654 loops=1)
  ->  Hash  (cost=314.10..314.10 rows=3936 width=321) (actual time=11.136..11.136 rows=3936 loops=1)
        Buckets: 4096  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1420kB
        ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=151.18..314.10 rows=3936 width=321) (actual time=2.142..7.524 rows=3936 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: ("teamToGroup"."groupId" = "group".id)
              ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=127.56..280.04 rows=3936 width=63) (actual time=1.697..4.839 rows=3936 loops=1)
                    Hash Cond: ("teamToGroup"."teamId" = team.id)
                    ->  Seq Scan on team_to_group "teamToGroup"  (cost=0.00..141.35 rows=4235 width=32) (actual time=0.006..0.767 rows=3936 loops=1)
                    ->  Hash  (cost=78.36..78.36 rows=3936 width=47) (actual time=1.668..1.668 rows=3936 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 4096  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 352kB
                          ->  Seq Scan on team  (cost=0.00..78.36 rows=3936 width=47) (actual time=0.008..0.558 rows=3936 loops=1)
              ->  Hash  (cost=18.83..18.83 rows=383 width=274) (actual time=0.436..0.436 rows=383 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 125kB
                    ->  Seq Scan on "group"  (cost=0.00..18.83 rows=383 width=274) (actual time=0.007..0.158 rows=383 loops=1)
Planning Time: 1.013 ms
Execution Time: 387.947 ms
```

The query

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
  SELECT "player"."id", 
         "player"."pid" 
   FROM "player" "player"
         LEFT JOIN "team" "team" ON "team"."id"="player"."teamId"  
         LEFT JOIN "goal" "goal" ON "goal"."playerId"="player"."id"  
         LEFT JOIN "team_to_group" "teamToGroup" ON "teamToGroup"."teamId"="team"."id"  
         LEFT JOIN "group" "group" ON "group"."id"="teamToGroup"."groupId";
```

Comment: You don’t have any filters so it’s unlikely indexing is going to help much (sure, you can use covering indexes to produce a secondary structure per table that only contains the columns you need, but that won’t help much). I don’t work with Postgres, but it looks to me like it’s returning 144,352 rows in 388 ms, do you really need it any faster than that? You’d be unlikely to want to get all those rows back frequently enough for that to be considered a problem. Or is there something else going on?

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is increase `work_mem` so that the hashes fit in a single batch.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that number of rows returned by the first hash right join is the same as the number returned by its parent (the top node).  While this could be an amazing coincidence, it sure looks like the joins to "team", "team_to_group" and "group" serve no actual purpose.  They don't contribute any columns, nor do they modify the counts, what other purpose would they serve?  Maybe they could just be removed.